# Exact dimensions in tcolorbox and tikz nodes

Tags: tcolorbox, polyglossia

I use tcolorbox in arabic document with polyglossia for theorems examples, and so. I put the titles of environments in tikz boxes what I put in the margin (in the right margin, the arabic is written in Right to Left mode)
I want (essentially for "small" examples but for others too...) to obtain good alignments of the boxes and for the nodes. Say a box and a node of the same height. I do it by hand, because I don't understand how tcolorbox decide where to put exactly the node... I give an ECM..

The tex file

```
    \documentclass[14pt]{extbook}%

    \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

    \usepackage{array}

     \tikzstyle{titlenode} =
     [draw=blue, thick, scale=.7, fill=red,% 
    line width=1pt, text=black, rectangle,
    font=\Large,
    left, minimum height=1cm]

    \newcounter{example}

    \newtcolorbox[auto counter,
        number within=section,
        number freestyle={\noexpand\arabic{section}\noexpand\alph{\tcbcounter}}]{example}[1][]{%
    enhanced,top=0mm,left=0pt,right=0pt,enlarge top by=\baselineskip/2+1mm,enlarge top at break by=0mm,pad at break=2mm,fontupper=\normalsize,
      overlay unbroken and first={%
        \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
        \pgfsetlayers{background,main}
    \node[titlenode] (B)
            at ([xshift=5mm,yshift=-6.3mm]frame.north east)
          {\strut\setlength{\extrarowheight}{-30.5pt}\textbf{$\begin{array}{c}
        \hline
        \rule{0pt}{2ex}
        \mbox{Example}
        \\
        \mbox{\Large\thetcbcounter}
        \rule{0pt}{1.5ex}
        \end{array}$}};
        },
    breakable,before=\par\smallskip\vspace{-10pt}\centering,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=white,colback=white,
    width=\textwidth,
    borderline north={2pt}{-3pt}{yellow},borderline south={2pt}{4.6pt}{blue},
    before upper={\parshape 4
            0pt \dimexpr \hsize-2.5cm\relax
            0pt \dimexpr \hsize-2.5cm\relax
            0pt \dimexpr \hsize-2.5cm\relax
            0pt \hsize},
    #1}

    \newtcolorbox[use counter from=example]{texample}[2][]{
    enhanced,boxrule=0pt,minipage boxed title=140mm,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=5mm,
    attach boxed title to top right={xshift=-5mm,yshift=-3.8mm,yshifttext=-1mm},
    coltitle=black,
    boxed title style={
    left=5pt,
    right=5pt,
    enhanced,
    arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
    colframe=blue,
    colback=yellow,
    colbacktitle=black,
    },
    enlarge top by=\baselineskip/2+1mm,enlarge top at break by=0mm,pad at break=2mm,fontupper=\normalsize,
      overlay unbroken and first={%
        \pgfdeclarelayer{background}
        \pgfsetlayers{background,main}
    \node[titlenode] (B)
            at ([xshift=5mm,yshift=-2.6mm]frame.north east)
          {\strut\setlength{\extrarowheight}{-30.5pt}\textbf{$\begin{array}{c}
        \hline
        \rule{0pt}{2ex}
        \mbox{Example}
        \\
        \mbox{\Large\thetcbcounter}
        \rule{0pt}{1.5ex}
        \end{array}$}};
        },
    breakable,before=\par\smallskip\centering,arc=0pt,colframe=white,colback=white,width=\textwidth,borderline south={2pt}{5pt}{blue},
    before upper={\parshape 2
            0pt \dimexpr \hsize-2.5cm\relax
            0pt \hsize},
    title={\strut\textbf{#2}\strut},
    #1}


    \begin{document}
    \setcounter{section}{1}

    \begin{example}
    A first example
    \end{example} 

    \vspace*{1cm}
    \begin{example}
    A first example. Aligned bottom
    \vspace*{.57cm}
    \end{example} 


    \begin{texample}{Titled example}
    By the same, I want that the title node rectangle will be exactly aligned with the box of title.
    \end{texample} 


    \end{document}
```

and its compilation with xelatex

[image]

I want that the title node rectangle will be exactly superposed on the borderline north (in yellow). One can see in the example 1a that the box is too small, and I want to arrange it in the bottom too, so that the borderline south will be exactly superposed under the title box. I arrange it by hand in the example 1b, in the text of the box by the command \vspace*{.57cm}. I want to do this automatically, i.e. to obtain box and node with the same height. How can I do this ?

By the same, I want to obtain good alignments of the title node rectangle and the box of the title. Many thanks

Comment: a good example that can help you is given in page 32 doc tcolorbox

Comment: which doc? The last one 3.40 or 3.03 ? What's the subject of this example ?

Comment: I have 3.21,  i will try to give you some help, but i am not free now, give me some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be helpful

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\newfontfamily{\arabicfont}[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{arabic}

\newcommand{\testarab}{%
اللغة العربية لغة جميله
اللغة العربية لغة جميله
اللغة العربية لغة جميله
اللغة العربية لغة جميله
اللغة العربية لغة جميله}

\newcounter{example}[section]
\renewcommand{\theexample}{\thesection.\alph{example}}
\newcommand{\exemplelabel}{%
المثال
\LR{\theexample}}

% this
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{example}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable,
colback=white, colframe=red, arc=0mm,
width=1.1\linewidth, rightrule=.1\linewidth, leftrule=0mm,
top=0mm, bottom=0mm, left=0mm, right=0mm,
colbacktitle=yellow, coltitle=black, title=#1,
overlay={%
\node[text width=.1\linewidth, align=center] at ([xshift=-.05\linewidth]frame.east) {\exemplelabel};}]}{%
\end{tcolorbox}}

% or this
\newenvironment{Example}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{example}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[skin=enhancedmiddle,breakable,
colback=white, colframe=red, arc=0mm,
width=1.1\linewidth, rightrule=.1\linewidth, leftrule=0mm,
top=0mm, bottom=0mm, left=0mm, right=0mm,
colbacktitle=yellow, coltitle=black, title=#1,
overlay={%
\node[text width=.1\linewidth, align=center] at ([xshift=-.05\linewidth]frame.east) {\exemplelabel};
\draw [blue,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)--+(\linewidth,0);
\draw [blue,line width=.5mm]([yshift=-.25mm]frame.north west)--+(\linewidth,0);}
]}{%
\end{tcolorbox}}
%---------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\testarab
\begin{example}[اللغة العربية]
\testarab
\end{example}

\begin{Example}[اللغة العربية]
\testarab
\end{Example}

\begin{example}
\testarab
\end{example}

\begin{Example}
\testarab
\end{Example}
\testarab

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** For fixed height I am not sure but you can try this

```
% this
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{example}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable,
colback=white, colframe=red, arc=0mm,
rightrule=.5mm, leftrule=0mm,
top=0mm, bottom=0mm, left=0mm, right=0mm,
colbacktitle=yellow, coltitle=black, title=#1,
overlay={%
\node[fill=red, below right, minimum height=3em, text width=1cm, align=center] at ([xshift=-.1mm]frame.north east) {\exemplelabel};}]}{%
\end{tcolorbox}}

% or this
\newenvironment{Example}[1][]{%
\refstepcounter{example}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[skin=enhancedmiddle,breakable,
colback=white, colframe=red, arc=0mm,
rightrule=.5mm, leftrule=0mm,
top=0mm, bottom=0mm, left=0mm, right=0mm,
colbacktitle=yellow, coltitle=black, title=#1,
overlay={%
\node[fill=red, below right, minimum height=3em, text width=1cm, align=center] at ([xshift=-.1mm]frame.north east) {\exemplelabel};
\draw [blue,line width=.5mm]([yshift=.25mm]frame.south west)--+(\linewidth,0);
\draw [blue,line width=.5mm]([yshift=-.25mm]frame.north west)--+(\linewidth,0);}
]}{%
\end{tcolorbox}}
```

Comment: It seems very helpful....and beautiful as the arabic language. I'll test it and keep you inform about in the final form. Many thanks

Comment: One thing. if I have a long example.. some thing like \begin{example}[اللغة العربية]
\testarab testarab testarab
\end{example}... the height will be too great and wil not be good for a title... How can I obtain a node of fixed height in this case ...some thing like 2cm for example.. ?

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna I edit my answer

Comment: would you see please these new question I've opened, strongly related (et meme based on !) with this one... 
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245494/customizing-breakable-boxes-with-tcolorbox